# bibliography - hanging+label

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

I'm using a simple `thebibliography` environment in my PhD thesis, using the `book` document style:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Kress10}
  \noun{Kress},G. 
  \emph{Multimodality: A Social Semiotic Approach to Contemporary Communication}.
  Oxon: 
  Routledge,
  2010.

\end{thebibliography}
```

However due to the demands here in my department two things must be suppressed:

1) I should get rid of the label (any kind) between brackets

2) The paragraph indenting should not be hanging, but totally aligned to the left

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the bibliography labels redefining the `@biblabel` command.
For example, if you want to just get rid of the square brackets, you should put that in the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{#1\hfill}
\makeatother
```

So, if you want to totally eliminate the label, use this

```
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{}
\makeatother
```

(I supppose you wanted to get rid of the square brackets too).

In this way, the items remains aligned to the left, answering your second questions.

Please, note that `\noun` is not a standard LateX macro, I think is something related to LyX. Use instead `\textsc` for standard LateX.